# LPTHW - ex48 - Handling exceptions and unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception-handling

This is my solution to the [exercise 48 of Learn Python the hard way by Zed Shaw](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html). Please visit the link for testing suite and requirements.

I'm worried about my the word banks I have created (COMPASS, VERBS, etc...) as this seems a duplication from the testing code.

I'm also afraid my handling might have gone overboard as all I needed it for was finding out which string items could be converted to integers.

```
1 COMPASS= ['north','south','east','west']$                               
2 VERBS = ['go', 'kill', 'eat']$                 
3 STOPS = ['the', 'in', 'of']$                   
4 NOUNS = ['bear', 'princess']$                  
5   $              
6 import string$ 
7 def scan(sentence):$                           
8     action = []$                               
9     #TODO: it seems there might be a way to  combine these if statments$       
10     for word in sentence.split(' '):$          
11         lword = string.lower(word)$            
12         try:$  
13             if lword in COMPASS:$              
14                 action.append(('direction', word))$                            
15             elif lword in VERBS:$              
16                 action.append(('verb', word))-$
17             elif lword in STOPS:$
18                 action.append(('stop', word))$
19             elif lword in NOUNS:$
20                 action.append(('noun', word))$
21             elif int(lword):$
22                 action.append(('number', int(word)))$
23         except:$                               
24             action.append(('error', word))$    
25     return action$                             
26 $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lword = string.lower(word)
```

There is no need to import the string module for this, you can use:

```
lword = word.lower()
```

As for this:

```
elif int(lword):
```

Probably better as

```
elif lword.isdigit():
```

As for your exception handling

```
     except:                                                              
         action.append(('error', word))
```

You should almost never use a bare except. You should catch a specific exception, and put a minimal amount of code in the try block. In this case you could have done something like

```
try:
   actions.append( ('number', int(word) )
except ValueError:
   actions.append( ('error', word) )
```